# Django - The current url didn’t match any of the these

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have Django 4.0.4
I tried the following url :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cp2/sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/
but it gives me error Page not found (404)

The current path, cp2/sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/, didn’t match any of these.

Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

I have 1370 patterns - where the correct pattern is on the line 268 as you can see from the debug exception page

cp2/ (?P<parent_element_name>\w+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/p/(?P<parent_field>\w+)/sbwblmnt/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$ [name='sbwblmnt_epec']

Thank you for the help

Comment: It has a `/p/` where your URL has an `o2m`, and then a `sbwblmnt` where your URL has a `wseclmts`.

Comment: I tried this code and it matches correctly
test_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cp2/sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/'
import re
url_pattern = r'(?P<parent_element_name>\w+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/p/(?P<parent_field>\w+)/sbwblmnt/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$'
pattern_re = re.compile(url_pattern)
match = pattern_re.search(test_url)

This used to match in the older Django version 3.x

Comment: Please don't consider the first cp2/

Comment: The pattern is intended to match the trailing part starting from >>. wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/

Comment: `pattern_re.match(test_url)` returns `None`, it should start with the element name, otherwise it will have to throw out all but the `wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/` part, and thus omit all the `sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/` as well...

Comment: It looks to me that your template has generated a *relative* URL path, and thus should render an *absolute* one, for example by using the `{% url ... %}` template tag: this is better than trying to "fix" this by letting the URL engine omit certain parts of the path, since it could eventually pick the wrong one, or will generate a path that is longer than what is allowed. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: THis is intended. I only want to match the end of the URL. I don't care about the initial part of the URL

Comment: but that is ugly, inefficient, and unsafe. Especially since a URL can have at most 2048 characters (including the protocol, hostname, path, *and* querystring). It also means that the regexes have a lot of extra work to match it properly. You should simply write the correct URLs in the template, not try to fix this by matching the trail of the path.

Comment: Actually it is some kind of cascaded calls that I need to keep its order.

Comment: then you need to encode these in the path, not use absolute paths, or you can work with the `HTTP_REFERER` key of the meta object, or session variables, or cookies, or some other mechanism.

Comment: It is not an absolute path. This used to work in the older Django versions. It only show when I upgraded to Django 4.0.x

Comment: yes, because now regexes are compiled by appending the regex parts of the url.

Comment: Thank you for this input >>yes, because now regexes are compiled by appending the regex parts of the url<<. I fixed it by adding (\w+/)* at the beginning

Comment: please don't: you are fixing a problem at the wrong place. You need to fix it where the URL is generated, not where it is analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wrote a *relative* URL in the template, so something like:

```
<a href="wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/">link</a>
```

This will append the path `wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/` to the already existing path, so if you browse this when the browser is visiting the `/cp2/sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/` path, it will visit `/cp2/sbwsec/1076/o2m/section/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/` path. This thus results in long URLs (that might even no longer fit in the 2048 character limit.

You should work with an *absolute* path, like:

```
<a href="/cp2/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/">link</a>
```

so with a *leading slash*. This will let the browser visit the `/cp2/wseclmts/47/p/element/sbwblmnt/1077/` path. You can work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to construct the path, so:

```
<a href="{% url 'sbwblmnt_epec' 'wseclmts' 47 'element' 1077 %}">link</a>
```

Where the first parameter `'sbwblmnt_epec'` is the name of the view, and the next parameters are values for the parameters. This will look to the patterns and construct the URL to visit the given path with the given parameters.

Comment: I updated my patter to be

Comment: (\w+/)*(?P<parent_element_name>\w+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/p/(?P<parent_field>\w+)/sbwblmnt/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$>> This will match the full url. In HTML it is the absolute path not a relative path

Comment: @AhmedHatem: well then it looks like you are constructing the absolute paths in the wrong way. Note that *John Mueller* at the *webmasters hangout in 2019* "*advised that URLs should be a maximum of 1,000 characters in length, otherwise problems could arise.*". Especially since both browsers and servers usually work with a maximum number of characters, and it is not known exactly what combination you will work and because sitemaps can get corrupted/invalid with https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/technical-seo/site-structure/url-length-how-long-can-a-url-be

Comment: By each time adding the path thus far somehow, you easily run out of characters. Furthermore if you need the referrer, or some other analytics, using the path is not the way to do this. You can work with the `HTTP_REFERRER`, use some JavaScript tooling to send data, etc.